# NFS automounts hang

Tags: nfs, mount, nis, automount

I have been mounting NFS shares on my x86 Ubuntu with NIS/am-utils fine for a long time, but today my system got into a state where it could no longer access automounted directories and instead frequently got hung up trying to access them, returning either "Input/output error" or "Permission denied" (almost randomly), as well as "stale file handle." I can, however, manually mount that share fine. Restarting am-utils doesn't help get my system out of its funk; is there any other way of getting my system un-stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 umount -f -l
```

always works for me on hung nfs mounts.

Comment: This didn't turn out to be the actual problem - the server was borked - but it's a good tip.